# how to solve the following: $x^{(\frac{1}{4}+\log_{6}{1})}=\sqrt6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> how to solve the following: $x^{(\frac{1}{4}+\log_{6}{1})}=\sqrt6$

I know that the answer is $36$ as I plug it into the equation it turns out to be true.

But what I do not understand is the process in which I obtain the answer $36$ and would like some assistance in figuring out what process I should take in order to obtain the answer

Comment: Start with $\log_6 1 = ?\,$

Comment: Then use $\sqrt{6}=6^\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: the question was modified sorry about that

Comment: I dont think thats permitted. Suddenly when you get hint for a question you cannot modify the question and ask a different doubt

Comment: On the latest iteration of this problem,$$x^{(\frac{1}{4}+\log_{6}{1})}=\sqrt6$$  $log_6 {1}=0$ leading to $x^\frac 1 4=\sqrt 6$

Comment: How do we end this question

Comment: I don't see why this question got all the negative votes or why it was closed. True it is not difficult but there are tons of similar questions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Taking logarithm wrt base $2,$

$$\log_2(x^2)=2+\log_25=\cdots+\log_2(2^2\cdot5)$$